# Trouble with select statement on three table join

Tags: sql, hsqldb

Im trying to write a query that will return a set of columns from three different tables.

The table that is link between the other two tables is called Table_A, it contains the keys of for the other two tables.
The second table is called the Table_B and the last table is called the Table_C.

Table_A columns.

> | a_ID (primary key)| b_ID (foreign key)| c_ID
>   (foreign key)| ..... |

Table_B columns

> |b_ID (primary key)| b1 | b2 | ...... |

Table_C columns

> | c_ID (primary key) | c1 | c2 | ...... |

This is my SQL Query below. (Im only concerned with the columns above although there are more in each table.)

```
SELECT b.b_ID
     , b.b1
     , b.b2
     , a.a_ID
     , c.c1
     , c.c2 
FROM Table_A AS a 
    JOIN Table_B AS b ON a.b_ID = b.b_ID
    JOIN Table_C AS c ON a.c_ID = c.c_ID
```

Im using open office for my projects and the error I'm getting is

> "Table not found in statement [    SELECT b.b_ID
>            , b.b1
>            , b.b2
>            , a.a_ID
>            , c.c1
>            , c.c2 
>       FROM Table_A AS a 
>           JOIN Table_B AS b ON a.b_ID = b.b_ID
>           JOIN Table_C AS c ON a.c_ID = c.c_ID]"

***For some reason if I change the select statement just to get all columns (****) it returns the correct results but I need to narrow it down to the columns listed in my query.***

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A AS a 
    JOIN Table_B AS b ON a.b_ID = b.b_ID
    JOIN Table_C AS c ON a.c_ID = c.c_ID'
```

EDIT: I have removed the actual table and column names so that you don't have to understand the story to help with the issue.

Comment: Could you post the working versions of the query?  The one that runs with `*` ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM registrationTbl AS a 
JOIN EventTbl AS b ON a.eventID = b.eventID
JOIN AttendeeTbl AS c ON a.attendeeID = c.AttendeeID WHERE b.startDate > '2013-10-01'

Comment: the INNER JOIN v JOIN doesn't change the type of error btw

Comment: are the column names repeated in the three tables? If you ran the query without the table prefix does it still error?

Comment: Your RDBMS is open office? Can you be more specific about that?

Comment: @Scorpi0: it's `hsqldb`, it's used on OpenOffice

Comment: Your columns may have been defined as case-sensitive, which means they should be double-quoted. Check the actual column names with `SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM ..` and double quote the ones you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your WHERE clause be:

```
WHERE b.eventStartDate > '2013-10-01'
```

?

This is a "spot the difference" type of question...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have edited the diagram to match the query. Thank you.

Comment: So it didn't solve your problem? Then you just need to triple-check if all the column and table names are fine... There won't be a better answer, I'm afraid :).

Comment: Thanks Frikoziod.. yeah Its driving me insane :P I'm 100% sure all the columns are char for char. I think its an open office issue now